# Cant format html table correctly

Tags: html, html-table

I want to achieve this table format

```
+--------------------+
|         1          |
|--------------------|
|   2         |3     |
|-------------|      |
|   4  |  5   |      |
|      |------|      |
|      | 8| 9 |      |
|      |  |   |------|
|      |  |   | 6 |7 |
+--------------------+
```

```html
<table border="1" ; width=50%">
<tbody  >
<tr><td colspan="5" >1</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" >2</td><td colspan="2" ; rowspan="3" >3</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="3" >4</td><td colspan="2" >5</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="2" >8</td><td rowspan="2" >9</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="1" >6</td><td>7</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This code should output the table. But the cell 8,9 doesn't work properly.It does show to be little higher than 6,7 if I zoom in.

It works perfectly however if I add a column before

```html
<table border="1" ; width=50%">
<tbody  >
<tr><td>#</td><td colspan="5" >1</td></tr>
<tr><td>#</td><td colspan="3" >2</td><td colspan="2" ; rowspan="3" >3</td></tr>
<tr><td>#</td><td rowspan="3" >4</td><td colspan="2" >5</td></tr>
<tr><td>#</td><td rowspan="2" >8</td><td rowspan="2" >9</td></tr>
<tr><td>#</td><td rowspan="1" >6</td><td>7</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What do you want to put in this table ?

Comment: Can you write your code as a snippet so it's easier for the rest of us to edit and tinker with?

Comment: You have a number of syntax errors in your HTML. Don't use `;`to separate attributes. Quote attribute values properly. Please click "Edit" below your question, and correct those mistakes in the snippets I created for you.

Comment: well, this is from my friend.i dont do html. he said its the new html standard

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one row with 5 cells. This row can be hidden.

Comment: `<tr><td colspan="5" >1</td></tr>` is a row with 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems to refactor your table html. I generate a new one.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="height: 21px;" colspan="5">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="height: 21px;" colspan="3">2</td>
      <td style="height: 21px;" colspan="2" rowspan="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="height: 63px;" rowspan="3">4</td>
      <td style="height: 21px;" colspan="2">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="height: 21px;" rowspan="2">6</td>
      <td style="height: 21px;" rowspan="2">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="height: 21px;">8</td>
      <td style="height: 21px;">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't just c&p invalid HTML; correct it.

Comment: @connexo thanks for hint. i generate new table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using CSS instead of table (tables are for showing tabular data, not for laying out your website), you can benefit greatly from the [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). If you don't know the advantages of relying on CSS Grid instead of HTML table: [CSS-Grid instead of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580720/css-grid-instead-of-table) , [CSS Grid vs Tables](https://medium.com/@mihanikk/css-grid-vs-tables-428adf12356a), [In what sense is a CSS grid a better option than a basic HTML table?](https://www.quora.com/In-what-sense-is-a-CSS-grid-a-better-option-than-a-basic-HTML-table?share=1) and more on your favorite search engine.

Here is a demo showcasing how grid can help you:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  aspect-ratio: 3; /* fluff for demo purpose */
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 7;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 5;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 5 / 6 / 7;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 7 / 3;
}

.div5 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 5;
}

.div6 {
  grid-area: 6 / 5 / 7 / 6;
}

.div7 {
  grid-area: 6 / 6 / 7 / 7;
}

.div8 {
  grid-area: 4 / 3 / 7 / 4;
}

.div9 {
  grid-area: 4 / 4 / 7 / 5;
}

/* fluff for demo purpose */
section {
  border: 1px orange dashed;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <section class="div1">1</section>
  <section class="div2">2</section>
  <section class="div3">3</section>
  <section class="div4">4</section>
  <section class="div5">5</section>
  <section class="div6">6</section>
  <section class="div7">7</section>
  <section class="div8">8</section>
  <section class="div9">9</section>
</div>
```

Generated with: [CSS Grid Generator](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/)